# Checking flow in graphs

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a toruble in checking if one grpahs is fullfiling the flow of infromation defined by another graph.
To do it i created class called FlowGraph as it is presented below.

```
class FlowGraph:
    G=nx.DiGraph()
    I=[ ]  #input
    O=[ ]  #output
```

Then i want to check if the input and output sets of nodes are the same and then perform checking on reachability each node from each other on both graph separately. How can I implement what is in parenthesis into python, networkx code.

```
def check(FF=FlowGraph, GG=FlowGraph):
  if FF.I==GG.I && FF.O==GG.O:
   for all u in FF.I:
     for all v in FF.O:
       if (flow from u to v in FF):
         if not (flow from u to v in GG):
           return False
         else:
           return True
   else:
    return False
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  This doesn't make sense.  Also, your pseudocode seems to be returning False is there is a flow in FF that is not in GG, but returning True if there is a flow in GG that is not in FF.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean that GG is reference graph and FF is given one. GG contains flow policy so FFshould fullfill this conditions. If the flow in GG for example x->z, y  then if in FF is no flow between x, y and z then policy is fullfiled. But if in FF the x->y then not cause GG does not allow flow between x and y

Comment: Your indentation is still off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have networkX installed on this machine, so I can't check this, but I think it will work.

```
def check(FF=FlowGraph, GG=FlowGraph):
    if FF.I != GG.I or FF.O !=  GG.O:
        return False
    for u in FF.I:
        reachF = { v for v in nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(FF,u) if v in FF.O }
        reachG = { v for v in nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(GG,u) if v in GG.O }
        if not reachF <= reachG:
            return False
    return True
```

For each input node `u`, we find all output nodes that are reachable from `u` in `FF` and all the output nodes that are reachable from `u` in `GG`. The policy is that every flow in `FF` must be a flow in `GG`, so `reachF` must be a subset of `reachG`.  If this isn't true, we fail immediately.  If all tests pass, then the graphs pass.

Comment: When i am testing the following function the first test is working properly i mean if FF.I != GG.I or FF.O !=  GG.O: but the rest is not working fine. when given graph has flow x->z and reference one has not got it then it is still true

Comment: Is the given graph FF and the reference graph GG or the other way around?

Comment: I got to where I could test it, and found my silly mistake.  I was testing for proper subset, not subset.  Editing the code now.